# Is it possible to get the current location of the friends by using their phone numbers in iphone sdk?

Tags: objective-c

I need to know is there any possibility or Open source available to get the current location of my friends by their phone numbers??

Anyone's help will be much appreciated.

Thanks all,

Monish.

Answer (score 1):

No it isn't possible. Unless you are the CIA, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Out of the box, no.

This would require a lot of server side stuff on your end.  Each friend would sign in with your app, and report a location to your server.  Then your app can talk to your server and fetch the locations of their friends.